# SQL Server: return the result of a select as a result of stored procedure execution

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is called from C#:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySP] 
    @ID int,
    @Exists bit OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @Exists = 0

    SELECT TOP 1 ID 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE ID = @ID

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT b.*
        FROM AnotherTable b
        INNER JOIN AnotherTable2 c ON b.ID = c.ID
        WHERE b.ID = @ID            
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       SET @Exists = 1

       SELECT TOP 0 NULL
   END
END
```

IF `@ID` does not exist in table `MyTable`, then I return the `SELECT b.*`, otherwise if `@ID` exists in the table, then I return no rows

The problem is that when `@ID` exists in the table, the stored procedure returns two tables as a result to C#, the one from `SELECT TOP 1` and the one from `SELECT b.*` and I only want to return SELECT b.* so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use exists for this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySP] 
    @ID int,
    @Exists bit OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SET @Exists = 0


   IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID)
   BEGIN
        SELECT b.*
        From   AnotherTable b
               INNER JOIN AnotherTable2 c on b.ID = c.ID
        Where  b.ID = @ID            
   END
   ELSE

   BEGIN
       SET @Exists = 1
       SELECT TOP 0 NULL
   END
END
```

Comment: This solution likes me. As I said to Gordon Linoff, this solution avoids sql server engine to execute an innecessary select by first checking if exists.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace all the logic with:

```
SELECT b.*
From AnotherTable b INNER JOIN
     AnotherTable2 c
     ON b.ID = c.ID
WHERE b.ID = @ID AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID);
```

And, if you don't want duplicates, you might as well do:

```
SELECT b.*
From AnotherTable b 
WHERE b.ID = @ID AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AnotherTable2 c WHERE b.ID = c.ID) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID);
```

Then, learn about table valued functions.  If you want to return a table, then the best approach -- if it is feasible -- is a function, not a stored procedure.
(Functions are more limited in their functionality, so this is not always possible.)

Comment: Problem with this approach is that entire select must be executed, and what I want is to avoid execute an innecessary select and generate inecessary sql server work if previous select (select top 1...) returns rows. This approach you say can be accomplished as well using a left join with MyTable and in the where clause filter by: where mytable.column is NULL. But this approach does not like me because as I say you make sql server work processing and innecessary select.

Comment: @user1624552  . . . You should run the queries and see how SQL Server optimizes them before coming to (incorrect) conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

The second result that you are getting is from the statement select top 0 null

Comment: You are not right. Second result:  SELECT TOP 0 NULL  is executed only if rows are returned by SELECT TOP 1 and in my casse SELECT TOP 1 is returning no rows, so first result SELECT b.*
        FROM AnotherTable b ... is executed instead.